# How to make a levels map page?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to make a level map page that shows the progress in the page. I want to make this page in an XML layout file and I'm actually trying to do something like this :
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmEtR.jpg)

I'm trying to make the path and put these levels in certain places, but without success.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: `I'm trying to make the path and put these levels in certain places, but without success.` please include what you've done so far

Comment: "Is there a way to do it?" - If I'd be literal I'd answer: "yes" (since others did it so there _is_ a way). However, it depends on what you've tried, your requirements, your setup etc. To improve on your questions please also read [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly add the code you are struggling with, thanks.

Comment: I added an image in the background,that was very easy . And for the rest i tried to do it with stepper control, but I couldn't find a way to bend the line between the levels. finally the result was very ugly 